# Applying trees to ordered discrete dependent variables?

Tags: classification, python, scikit-learn, cart, ordinal-data

I am trying to use trees to model the number of months counties take to fully recover following an extreme weather event. Since I am looking at count of months, I have an ordered discrete dependent variable. I started by running classification trees; however, it seems like they are not fully capturing the nature of the data. I want to try accounting for the ordered nature of the dependent variable by fitting trees similar to how ordered logits are fit. I imagine that this is mostly a matter of fitting either a classification or regression tree, and calculating error correctly. I tried to find examples of or documentation for taking this kind of approach, but could not find anything. I am open to all advice and direction. I am working with the sklearn package for Python.

Comment: Why not treat it as continuous? A prediction of e.g. 7.4 months seems fine, and you can always round afterward.

Comment: Doesn't applying a model that assumes a continuous dependent variable onto a discrete variable produce biased results?